# Nodemail x Node.js: Failed auth although tested with success

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am having a problem with a nodemailer Firebase Function supposed to send emails through an SMTP transporter.

It is strange because I am testing my connection with success using:

```
// check server readiness
const serverReady = await new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
  transporter.verify( (err: any, succ: any) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      resolve(false);
    } else {
      console.log('Server is ready to take our messages');
      resolve(true);
    }
  });
})
```

Which prints `Server is ready to take our messages`.

Then after setting up my envelope andsending it with th `.sendMail` method I get this error:

```
Unhandled error { Error: Mail command failed: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:777:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1546:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1028:18)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:935:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:742:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:601:20)
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '530 5.5.1 Authentication Required.',
  responseCode: 530,
  command: 'MAIL FROM' }
```

The error is pretty clear: `Failed Auth` but it's  strange since the test worked earlier!

Connection parameters are:

```
// options to connect to server
const smtpOptions = {
  host: 'smtp.zoho.eu',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: functions.config().nodemailer.user,
    pass: functions.config().nodemailer.pass
  }
};

// transporter for sending the email
const transporter = nodeMail.createTransport( smtpOptions );
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Cab you also add the transporter initialisation.

Comment: Added at the end of the question!

Comment: are you sure the from address you are using is allowed

Answer (score 0):

`transporter.verify` only tests the connection and authentication, it looks like the that you are not authorised to use the particular `MAIL FROM` address.

Comment: In your experience, would using DKIM signature help?

Comment: Yes it improves deliverability. I have configured DKIM at the domain level  so that Amazon SES will add a signature with every email sent using their service. Are you considering to use SES

Comment: I am now testing with an added DKIM signature, if it gets resolved I will let you guys know

Comment: It still didn't change anything and I have the exact same error. I really don't know what to do. I have full access to the From email, enter the correct username and password, parameters are correct and the envelope looks good when I log it in my servers.

Comment: I looked into the source code, what makes my code fail is this condition:
(Number(str.charAt(0)) !== 2) because this is apparently true. How can my recipient be returning 2? What Character has a value 2?

Comment: Can you log `str`.